Use web component in react-native-expo using module federation
I want to use microfrontend of web-component in react-native-expo using module federation. There are 4 different microfrontends 2 of them required some request parameters. I tried to Re.Pack package and module-federation. it didn't work and also tried several other things as well. Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

I'm also interested in this. Is it even possible to pull web components into a React Native app? Or is Re.Pack only for sharing modules between React Native apps (not web)?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
